# How to use a case statement in regexp_replace function？

Tags: oracle, case, regexp-replace

I am trying to use case statement in regexp_replace function, Because I want to replace it according to different situations. The SQL looks like that:

```
col str for a15
with temp as
(
select 'A*((B*C)+D)' expre1 from dual union all
select 'A*((B*C)-D)' expre1 from dual union all
select '((A*B)+C)*D' expre1 from dual union all
select '((A*B)+C)+D' expre1 from dual union all
select 'A*((B+C)+D)' expre1 from dual union all
select '((A*B)+C)-D' expre1 from dual union all
select 'A*((B+C)-D)' expre1 from dual union all
select '((A*B)+C)/D' expre1 from dual union all
select '((A*B)-C)*D' expre1 from dual union all
select '((A*B)-C)+D' expre1 from dual union all
select 'A*((B-C)+D)' expre1 from dual union all
select 'A*((B-C)-D)' expre1 from dual union all
select '((A*B)-C)-D' expre1 from dual union all
select '((A*B)-C)/D' expre1 from dual union all
select 'A*((B/C)+D)' expre1 from dual union all
select 'A*((B/C)-D)' expre1 from dual union all
select 'A+((B*C)+D)' expre1 from dual union all
select 'A+((B*C)-D)' expre1 from dual union all
select '((A+B)+C)*D' expre1 from dual union all
select 'A+((B+C)+D)' expre1 from dual union all
select '((A+B)+C)+D' expre1 from dual union all
select 'A+((B+C)-D)' expre1 from dual union all
select '((A+B)+C)-D' expre1 from dual union all
select '((A+B)+C)/D' expre1 from dual union all
select '((A+B)-C)*D' expre1 from dual union all
select 'A+((B-C)+D)' expre1 from dual union all
select '((A+B)-C)+D' expre1 from dual union all
select '((A+B)-C)-D' expre1 from dual union all
select 'A+((B-C)-D)' expre1 from dual union all
select '((A+B)-C)/D' expre1 from dual union all
select 'A+((B/C)+D)' expre1 from dual union all
select 'A+((B/C)-D)' expre1 from dual union all
select 'A-((B*C)+D)' expre1 from dual union all
select 'A-((B*C)-D)' expre1 from dual union all
select '((A-B)+C)*D' expre1 from dual union all
select 'A-((B+C)+D)' expre1 from dual union all
select '((A-B)+C)+D' expre1 from dual union all
select 'A-((B+C)-D)' expre1 from dual union all
select '((A-B)+C)-D' expre1 from dual union all
select '((A-B)+C)/D' expre1 from dual union all
select '((A-B)-C)*D' expre1 from dual union all
select 'A-((B-C)+D)' expre1 from dual union all
select '((A-B)-C)+D' expre1 from dual union all
select 'A-((B-C)-D)' expre1 from dual union all
select '((A-B)-C)-D' expre1 from dual union all
select '((A-B)-C)/D' expre1 from dual union all
select 'A-((B/C)+D)' expre1 from dual union all
select 'A-((B/C)-D)' expre1 from dual union all
select 'A/((B*C)+D)' expre1 from dual union all
select 'A/((B*C)-D)' expre1 from dual union all
select '((A/B)+C)*D' expre1 from dual union all
select 'A/((B+C)+D)' expre1 from dual union all
select '((A/B)+C)+D' expre1 from dual union all
select '((A/B)+C)-D' expre1 from dual union all
select 'A/((B+C)-D)' expre1 from dual union all
select '((A/B)+C)/D' expre1 from dual union all
select '((A/B)-C)*D' expre1 from dual union all
select 'A/((B-C)+D)' expre1 from dual union all
select '((A/B)-C)+D' expre1 from dual union all
select 'A/((B-C)-D)' expre1 from dual union all
select '((A/B)-C)-D' expre1 from dual union all
select '((A/B)-C)/D' expre1 from dual union all
select 'A/((B/C)+D)' expre1 from dual union all
select 'A/((B/C)-D)' expre1 from dual
)
select expre1
       ,regexp_replace(expre1,'\(\(([ABCD])([\*/\+\-])([ABCD])\)([\*/\+\-])([ABCD])\)',
        case
          when '\4' = '+' or '\4' = '-' then '(\1\2\3\4\5)'
          else '((\1\2\3)\4\5)'
        end)  str
from temp
where regexp_instr(expre1,'\(\(([ABCD])([\*/\+\-])([ABCD])\)([\*/\+\-])([ABCD])\)') > 0;
```

bug the result is as follows：

```
EXPRE1                    STR
------------------------- ---------------
A*((B*C)+D)               A*((B*C)+D)
A*((B*C)-D)               A*((B*C)-D)
((A*B)+C)*D               ((A*B)+C)*D
((A*B)+C)+D               ((A*B)+C)+D
A*((B+C)+D)               A*((B+C)+D)
((A*B)+C)-D               ((A*B)+C)-D
A*((B+C)-D)               A*((B+C)-D)
```

It's looks that the code "when '\4'" considered as a string '\4' but not regular expression. My goal is to remove parentheses. So, how can I modify it?

Comment: Please include clear before and after data.  Note that Oracle regex is not suitable for processing nested parentheses.  To do that, you need a proper parser.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it could be done without regexp. With your sample data - something like this

```sql
Select  EXPRE1,
        Case  When Instr(EXPRE1, '-(') > 0 Then EXPRE1
              When Instr(EXPRE1, '*') = 0 And Instr(EXPRE1, '/') = 0
                  Then '(' || Replace(Replace(EXPRE1, '(', ''), ')', '') || ')'
              When SubStr(EXPRE1, 4, 1) In('+', '-') And Instr(EXPRE1, '*', 1, 1) = Length(EXPRE1) - 1 And Instr(EXPRE1, '/') = 0
                  Then  '(' || 
                        Replace(
                          Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(EXPRE1, '(', ''), ')', ''), ')+', '+'), ')-', '-')
                        , '*', ')*')
              When Instr(EXPRE1, '*', 1, 1) = 2 And Instr(EXPRE1, '*', 1, 2) = 0 And Instr(EXPRE1, '/') = 0
                  Then SubStr(EXPRE1, 1,  2) || '(' || Replace(Replace(SubStr(EXPRE1, 3), '(', ''), ')', '') || ')'
              When Instr(EXPRE1, '*', 1, 1) < Length(EXPRE1) - 1 And Instr(EXPRE1, '/') = 0
                  Then EXPRE1
              --
              When SubStr(EXPRE1, 4, 1) In('+', '-') And Instr(EXPRE1, '/', 1, 1) = Length(EXPRE1) - 1 And Instr(EXPRE1, '*') = 0
                  Then  '(' || 
                        Replace(
                          Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(EXPRE1, '(', ''), ')', ''), ')+', '+'), ')-', '-')
                        , '/', ')/')
              When Instr(EXPRE1, '/', 1, 1) = 2 And Instr(EXPRE1, '/', 1, 2) = 0 And Instr(EXPRE1, '*') = 0
                  Then SubStr(EXPRE1, 1,  2) || '(' || Replace(Replace(SubStr(EXPRE1, 3), '(', ''), ')', '') || ')'
              --
              When Length(EXPRE1) - Length(Replace(EXPRE1, '*')) > 1 OR Length(EXPRE1) - Length(Replace(EXPRE1, '/')) > 1 OR
                  (Length(EXPRE1) - Length(Replace(EXPRE1, '*')) = 1 And Length(EXPRE1) - Length(Replace(EXPRE1, '/')) = 1)
                  Then EXPRE1
        Else  '((' || 
              SubStr(Replace(EXPRE1, '((', ''), 1, InStr(Replace(EXPRE1, '((', ''), ')', 1, 1)) ||
              SubStr(Replace(EXPRE1, '((', ''), InStr(Replace(EXPRE1, '((', ''), ')', 1, 1) + 1)
        End "STR"
From    temp
```

```sql
/*
EXPRE1      STR                                     
----------- ----------------------------------------
A*((B*C)+D) A*((B*C)+D)                             
A*((B*C)-D) A*((B*C)-D)                             
((A*B)+C)*D ((A*B)+C)*D                             
((A*B)+C)+D ((A*B)+C)+D                             
A*((B+C)+D) A*(B+C+D)                               
((A*B)+C)-D ((A*B)+C)-D                             
A*((B+C)-D) A*(B+C-D)                               
((A*B)+C)/D ((A*B)+C)/D                             
((A*B)-C)*D ((A*B)-C)*D                             
((A*B)-C)+D ((A*B)-C)+D                             
A*((B-C)+D) A*(B-C+D)                               
A*((B-C)-D) A*(B-C-D)                               
((A*B)-C)-D ((A*B)-C)-D                             
((A*B)-C)/D ((A*B)-C)/D                             
A*((B/C)+D) A*((B/C)+D)                             
A*((B/C)-D) A*((B/C)-D)                             
A+((B*C)+D) A+((B*C)+D)                             
A+((B*C)-D) A+((B*C)-D)                             
((A+B)+C)*D (A+B+C)*D                               
A+((B+C)+D) (A+B+C+D)                               
((A+B)+C)+D (A+B+C+D)                               
A+((B+C)-D) (A+B+C-D)                               
((A+B)+C)-D (A+B+C-D)                               
((A+B)+C)/D (A+B+C)/D                               
((A+B)-C)*D (A+B-C)*D                               
A+((B-C)+D) (A+B-C+D)                               
((A+B)-C)+D (A+B-C+D)                               
((A+B)-C)-D (A+B-C-D)                               
A+((B-C)-D) (A+B-C-D)                               
((A+B)-C)/D (A+B-C)/D                               
A+((B/C)+D) ((A+B/C)+D)                             
A+((B/C)-D) ((A+B/C)-D)                             
A-((B*C)+D) A-((B*C)+D)                             
A-((B*C)-D) A-((B*C)-D)                             
((A-B)+C)*D (A-B+C)*D                               
A-((B+C)+D) A-((B+C)+D)                             
((A-B)+C)+D (A-B+C+D)                               
A-((B+C)-D) A-((B+C)-D)                             
((A-B)+C)-D (A-B+C-D)                               
((A-B)+C)/D (A-B+C)/D                               
((A-B)-C)*D (A-B-C)*D                               
A-((B-C)+D) A-((B-C)+D)                             
((A-B)-C)+D (A-B-C+D)                               
A-((B-C)-D) A-((B-C)-D)                             
((A-B)-C)-D (A-B-C-D)                               
((A-B)-C)/D (A-B-C)/D                               
A-((B/C)+D) A-((B/C)+D)                             
A-((B/C)-D) A-((B/C)-D)                             
A/((B*C)+D) A/((B*C)+D)                             
A/((B*C)-D) A/((B*C)-D)                             
((A/B)+C)*D ((A/B)+C)*D                             
A/((B+C)+D) A/(B+C+D)                               
((A/B)+C)+D ((A/B)+C)+D                             
((A/B)+C)-D ((A/B)+C)-D                             
A/((B+C)-D) A/(B+C-D)                               
((A/B)+C)/D ((A/B)+C)/D                             
((A/B)-C)*D ((A/B)-C)*D                             
A/((B-C)+D) A/(B-C+D)                               
((A/B)-C)+D ((A/B)-C)+D                             
A/((B-C)-D) A/(B-C-D)                               
((A/B)-C)-D ((A/B)-C)-D                             
((A/B)-C)/D ((A/B)-C)/D                             
A/((B/C)+D) A/((B/C)+D)                             
A/((B/C)-D) A/((B/C)-D)                           */
```

NOTE: Probably Didn't cover all the specific cases, but you'll get the picture ...
You can test if the results are same if you add a small function to WITH clause. The query above will be cte conversions in the code below:

```sql
WITH  
Function math(p_formula VarChar2) Return Number AS
  BEGIN
      Declare 
          cmd             VarChar2(512) := 'Select ' || p_formula || ' From Dual' ;
          chk             Number;
          v_formula       VarChar2(512) := p_formula;
      Begin
               execute immediate cmd InTo chk;
              RETURN chk;
      End;
  END;
    conversions AS 
      ( ... code from above sql ... 
      )
Select *
From (  SELECT  EXPRE1, STR, 
                Round(Math(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(EXPRE1, 'A', '1'), 'B', '2'), 'C', '3'), 'D', '4') ), 2) "VAL_EXPRE1",
                Round(Math(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(STR, 'A', '1'), 'B', '2'), 'C', '3'), 'D', '4') ), 2) "VAL_STR",
                Round(Math(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(EXPRE1, 'A', '1'), 'B', '2'), 'C', '3'), 'D', '4') ), 2) -
                Round(Math(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(STR, 'A', '1'), 'B', '2'), 'C', '3'), 'D', '4') ), 2) "DIFF"
        From  conversions
      )
Where DIFF != 0
```

... all the results are equal

```sql
--    no rows selected
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, your regular expression is not correct as `[\*/\+\-]` matches either `\` or `*` or `/` or `\` or `+` or `\` or `-`. What you want is just `[*/+-]`.

While your code is valid syntax, it is not going to give you the output you expect as the `CASE` expression will not be evaluated as part of the regular expression so `when '\4' = '+' or '\4' = '-'` is never going to be true as `\4` will be evaluated as the literal string `\4` and not as the 4th match parameter returned from the regular expression.

You can use two mutually-exclusive regular expressions matching `[*/]` in one and `[+-]` in the second:

```sql
SELECT expre1,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(
         REGEXP_REPLACE(
           expre1,
           '\(\(([ABCD][*/+-][ABCD])\)([+-][ABCD])\)',
           '(\1\2)'
         ),
         '\(\(([ABCD][*/+-][ABCD])\)([*/][ABCD])\)',
         '((\1)\2)'
       ) AS str
FROM   temp
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE(expre1,'\(\(([ABCD][*+-][ABCD])\)([*/+-][ABCD])\)');
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

| EXPRE1 | STR |
| --- | --- |
| A*((B*C)+D) | A*(B*C+D) |
| A*((B*C)-D) | A*(B*C-D) |
| ((A*B)+C)*D | (A*B+C)*D |
| ((A*B)+C)+D | (A*B+C)+D |
| A*((B+C)+D) | A*(B+C+D) |
| ((A*B)+C)-D | (A*B+C)-D |
| A*((B+C)-D) | A*(B+C-D) |
| ((A*B)+C)/D | (A*B+C)/D |
| ((A*B)-C)*D | (A*B-C)*D |
| ((A*B)-C)+D | (A*B-C)+D |
| A*((B-C)+D) | A*(B-C+D) |
| A*((B-C)-D) | A*(B-C-D) |
| ((A*B)-C)-D | (A*B-C)-D |
| ((A*B)-C)/D | (A*B-C)/D |
| A+((B*C)+D) | A+(B*C+D) |
| A+((B*C)-D) | A+(B*C-D) |
| ((A+B)+C)*D | (A+B+C)*D |
| A+((B+C)+D) | A+(B+C+D) |
| ((A+B)+C)+D | (A+B+C)+D |
| A+((B+C)-D) | A+(B+C-D) |
| ((A+B)+C)-D | (A+B+C)-D |
| ((A+B)+C)/D | (A+B+C)/D |
| ((A+B)-C)*D | (A+B-C)*D |
| A+((B-C)+D) | A+(B-C+D) |
| ((A+B)-C)+D | (A+B-C)+D |
| ((A+B)-C)-D | (A+B-C)-D |
| A+((B-C)-D) | A+(B-C-D) |
| ((A+B)-C)/D | (A+B-C)/D |
| A-((B*C)+D) | A-(B*C+D) |
| A-((B*C)-D) | A-(B*C-D) |
| ((A-B)+C)*D | (A-B+C)*D |
| A-((B+C)+D) | A-(B+C+D) |
| ((A-B)+C)+D | (A-B+C)+D |
| A-((B+C)-D) | A-(B+C-D) |
| ((A-B)+C)-D | (A-B+C)-D |
| ((A-B)+C)/D | (A-B+C)/D |
| ((A-B)-C)*D | (A-B-C)*D |
| A-((B-C)+D) | A-(B-C+D) |
| ((A-B)-C)+D | (A-B-C)+D |
| A-((B-C)-D) | A-(B-C-D) |
| ((A-B)-C)-D | (A-B-C)-D |
| ((A-B)-C)/D | (A-B-C)/D |
| A/((B*C)+D) | A/(B*C+D) |
| A/((B*C)-D) | A/(B*C-D) |
| A/((B+C)+D) | A/(B+C+D) |
| A/((B+C)-D) | A/(B+C-D) |
| A/((B-C)+D) | A/(B-C+D) |
| A/((B-C)-D) | A/(B-C-D) |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UGif_hZx)